# I'm getting an error when I want to use \usepackage{tkz-euclide}

Tags: tkz-euclide

I am writing a manuscript to be considered for publication in the Combinatorics, Probability and Computing journal. I'm using the journal's template which can be obtained through https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/combinatorics-probability-and-computing/information/instructions-contributors#. I need to use tkz-euclide package but every time I add the package I'm getting an error that reads as follows:

[image]

My working trial is as follows:

```
\documentclass{cpc}
%\title[Book reviews]{Book reviews}
\title[A novel grid-based proving technique for generated graph of FTTM pseudo degree]{A novel grid-based proving technique for generated graph of FTTM pseudo degree}
\author[Amirul Aizad Ahmad Fuad and Tahir Ahmad]{Amirul Aizad Ahmad Fuad and Tahir Ahmad\thanks{Corresponding author}\\
\affilskip Department of Mathematical Sciences \\
\affilskip Faculty of Science \\
\affilskip Universiti Teknologi Malaysia \\
\affilskip 81310 Johor Bahru, Malaysia \\}


\recdate{2 October 2003}
\pubyear{2003}
\pagerange{\pageref{firstpage}--\pageref{lastpage}}
\doi{S0963548301004989}
\volume{00}

\def\eg{{\it e.g.\ }}
\def\etc{{\it etc}}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,amssymb,longtable,tikz,tikz-cd,cite,mathtools,float}

%\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\newcommand{\midarrow}{\tikz \draw[-triangle 90] (0,0) -- +(.1,0);}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{0}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\label{firstpage}
\maketitle%[P]

\begin{abstract}
Fuzzy topological topographic mapping $(FTTM)$ is a mathematical model that consists of a set of homeomorphic topological spaces designed to solve the neuromagnetic inverse problem. The special characteristic of $FTTM$, namely the homeomorphisms between its components, allows the generation of new $FTTM$. These generated $FTTM$s can be represented as pseudo graphs. A graph of pseudo degree zero is a special type of pseudo graph where each of the $FTTM$'s components differs from its adjacent. Previous researchers have investigated and conjectured the number of generated $FTTM$ pseudo degree zero with respect to $n$ number of components and $k$ number of versions.  In this paper, the conjecture is proven analytically.  The grid-based method of proving is new, whereby some definitions and properties are introduced and developed along the way, respectively.  It offers an edge in proving, in particular, the capability of visualizing the problem in a $2$-dimensional space.

\begin{tabular}{lp{8cm}}
2020 \textit{Mathematics subject classification:}&{Primary 05C62} \\&{Secondary 05C50}
\end{tabular}
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried loading `hyperref` *last*?

Comment: Incidentally, is the `cpc` LaTeX document class available online?

Comment: @Mico There is a link to the class in the question.

Comment: If all else fails, you could create all the diagrams in a separate file using `\documentclass{standalone} \usepackage{tkz-euclide} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{document}`, and use `\includegraphics` in your main file to include that PDF.

Comment: I need the use the cpc class to conform with the journal's format. @TorbjørnT.

Comment: You misunderstood, I was suggesting you create the diagrams by themselves in a separate file, and then include that PDF as an image in the document with the `cpc` class.

Comment: The problem comes from 'numprint` or from `cpc` (see my answer). Specifically, it's the definition of "maketitle" that seems to be at fault. Perhaps you just need to redefine `\ maketitle`

Comment: Ok I got it. Thank you @TorbjørnT.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes It's a good solution to  create the diagrams by themselves in a separate file but the simplest way to avoid using `maketitle`. We create a title separately.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not exactly `tkz-euclide` but `numprint`. Unfortunately `tkz-euclide` loads `tkz-base` which uses `numprint`. There are several possibilities, but some of them take time.

1) Modify `tkz-euclide` to make it an independent version of `tkz-base` and make only Euclidean geometry strictly it will be `tkz-elements`. It's progressing, but I have many other projects to finish before that.

2) Modify `tkz-base` to allow the use of `siunits`. I don't know enough about the latter to do this work quickly.

3) See where the error comes from and try to work around it ... that's what I propose to do first.

The problem:

```
\documentclass{cpc}
\usepackage{numprint}
\author{Alain Matthes}
\title{Altermundus}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

`Latex Error: ./cam.tex:8 Missing # inserted in alignment preamble.`

Let's see what the `cpc.cls` class does. It redefines a lot of things.
I incorporate the definition of `maketitle` and comment out the lines that cause problems.

```
\documentclass{cpc}
\usepackage{numprint}
\author{Alain Matthes}
\title{Altermundus}

\makeatletter
\def\author@tabular{\def\@halignto{}\@authortable}
\let\endauthor@tabular=\endtabular

\def\author@tabularcr{{\ifnum0=`}\fi
% \it removed and \footnotesize added 
 \@xtabularcr[5\p@]\footnotesize\ignorespaces}
\def\@authortable{
\leavevmode \hbox \bgroup $\let\@acol\@tabacol
 \let\@classz\@tabclassz \let\@classiv\@tabclassiv
 \let\\\author@tabularcr \@tabarray
 }

\def\@maketitle#1{%
  \newpage
  \vspace*{-25\p@}%
  \noindent\linedouble\\[7\p@]
   {\centering
   \sp@head{#1}%
    {\LARGE\strut \bf \@title \par}%
    \setbox0=\vbox{\let\thanks\relax \LARGE\strut \bf \@title \par}%
    \vskip-\ht0
    \vskip 75\p@
    \linethin\\[7\p@]
    {\normalsize
    % \begin{author@tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
       \@author
    % \end{author@tabular}
      }%
     \ifrecdateused
       \vskip 3\p@
       {\hfil\small\strut\it Received \@recdate\hfil}%
     \else \par
     \fi
  }%
  \noindent
  \vskip -11\p@% remove the last \par
  \vskip 39\p@
  }% two line space

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

I think the problem comes from `author@tabular'.
Either you modify`maketitle`to complete the title, or you ask another question about`numprint' and `author@tabular'.

Perhaps this bug is known